# Copy Constructor or overloading Operator= with an inherited list of pointers

Tags: c++, overloading, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a Class that inherit from a list of pointers, example:

```
Class C : protected list<Type*>
```

Now, i want to overload the operator= (and to write the copy constructor). Should i iterate the list making a new Type for each pointer inside the list?

```
void C::operator=(const C& c)
{
    if(!(*this)==c))
    {
        clear();
        for(list<Type*>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); it++)
        {
           Type* cp = new Type((*it)); //or doing cp=&(*it) after the new
           push_back(cp);
        }
    }
}
```

or can i do this?

```
void C::operator=(const C& c)
{
    if(!(*this)==c))
    {
        clear();
        for(list<Type*>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); it++)
        {
           Type* cp = it; //or cp=&(*it)
           push_back(cp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to be able to help you, we will need a [mcve]. Please add missing information.

Comment: You're going to have to figure out the answer yourself. Only you know all the rules about who owns which objects in your program, and when their lifetime begins and when their lifetime should end. Noone on stackoverflow.com knows how the rest of your program works, so nobody can tell you. You need to understand how objects work in C++, when they get created, and when they should be destroyed, and apply that to your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So i have to know if there is a `new` statement before i add the objects in that list. But i want to know if i can copy the elements doing `pointer = pointer_copied`, i think of yes, i will have two lists with pointers to the same addresses !?

Comment: Unrelated: `if(!(*this)==c)) { ... }` should be `if(this == &c) return;` if it's the addresses you want to compare and not for equality. You now compare for equality. Thanks @JHBonarius :-D

Comment: Oh, i use `!(==)` when i have not a not-equal-to operator overloaded in that class, but a `==`. This is the pointer to the class, `(*this)` and `c` the actual objects.

Comment: The best resource for learning how pointers and objects work is your C++ book. stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ book.

Comment: @AmarAnto Even if you do have `operator==` the check for equality before assigning is rarely useful - but will cost time. You should test for self assignment if that could hurt your object though, so you are on the right track. Comparing the addresses is usually the way to go.

Comment: I mean, i know that i can do `pointer = pointer_copied`, it's not a question of pointers, i was referring to the possibility of only copying the address, there's no necessity to create a new object.

Comment: Since neither of your options compile (there's a problem converting `const_iterator` to `iterator`), you should use neither. OK, that much is easy to fix, but the second option still has a compile error converting an iterator to a pointer, so that's still a no-go. *(Please make sure your code compiles without errors before posting your question -- unless you are asking why it does not compile.)*

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, for the compiling error the problem is the iterator, `*it` is the pointer, `*(*it)` the object, my bad.

Comment: Also, if you assignment is complex, you want to use the copy and swap idiom. This help make the code exception safe (either full copy or no copy) and reduce code duplication.

Comment: It might be a bad idea to inherit from a standard container class. Private or protected inheritance could be more OK than public, but simple containment does the job just as well.

Comment: What is not fully clear to me: do you want to copy the list of pointers? Or do you want to create a new list of objects with pointers, each a copy of the original? Please clarify in your question.

Comment: Only to copy the list of pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited my answer, as this is a homework exercise

In a normal application you shouldn't derive from a STL container, their destructors are not virtual. Thus when `C` is destroyed, the `std::list<T>` will remain, causing a memory leak. They are not meant to be inherited form in the first place...

In a normal design, you would have the list as an object:

```
#include <list>

template<typename T>
class C {
private:
    std::list<T*> lst;
public:
    C& operator=(const C& c) {
        if (this != &c) {
            lst = c.lst;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

What I would consider a **GOOD** exercise is that you implement a `MyList` class, making *everything* from scratch.
But it is common knowledge that professors make student do weird illogical stuff. So lets assume you indeed want to derive from `std::list` and only overload `operator=`, doing the copy yourself

```
#include <list>

template<typename T> 
class C : protected std::list<T*>
{
public:
    constexpr C& operator=(C const& c) noexcept {
        if (this != &c) {
            this->clear();
            // copy
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now, how do you copy... many flavors! There's the good-old C-style loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i) this->push_back(c[i]);
```

There's the iterator loop:

```
for (std::list<T*>::const_iterator it = c.cbegin(); it != c.cend(); ++it) this->push_back(*it);
```

There's the iterator loop with `auto` and generalized accessors:

```
for (auto it = std::cbegin(c); it != std::cend(c); ++it) this->push_back(*it);
```

There's range-based for loops:

```
for (auto const& el : c) this->push_back(el);
```

There's algorithms, like `std::for_each`

```
std::for_each(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c), [this](T* ptr) { this->push_back(ptr); });
```

... and `std::copy`

```
std::copy(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c), std::back_inserter(*this));
```

note that `std::back_inserter` is an iterator that performs a `push_back` while iterating.

And in the future (C++20) we will have ranges, so you can write something like

```
std::ranges::copy(c, *this);
```

Although I'm not sure that's correct...

Choose your poison!

Comment: Thanks! It is always the right way to use the existing methods instead of reinventing all, but it is an 'exercise' :/

Comment: @AmarAnto ah... you mean you have a bad professor... I feel sorry for you. It would be a better exercise just to create your own list class from scratch... Well anyhow, just don't forget to call the base-class operator= then...

Comment: Those are not the reasons not to derive from a standard container. And your statement about overloading `operator=` is wrong: the whole point is the OP wants to perform a deep copy. Yours does not; it literally just delegates to the base `operator=` and thus is without any purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica does he??? but he doesn;t have access to the internals of `std::list`. So he would just be building a wrapper class.... a wrapped derivative class... That doesn't make any sense at all :/

Comment: No, `std::list` does not perform a deep copy.

Comment: `std::list` acts like containers do. Pointers are copied - but not what they point at. A `std::list` of actual objects would have been deep copied - but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do!

The first performs a *deep copy*; the second just performs a shallow copy of the pointers in the list, and thus does nothing that the original `std::list` implementation didn't do.

Also, `if(!(*this)==c))` is wrong; it has too many `)` and was probably intended to be `if (this != &c)`.

Comment: @JHBonarius This is a Q&A, not a chatroom. Answering the question takes place in answers.